# Reference viewControllers for Social Media App Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently trying to clone Instagram for practice. I have created all the tabBar controllers. I want my user to be able to go to another user's account my tapping the username on the post. And then user can see their posts by tapping one of their posts. For this, do I add new ViewControllers or reference the same ones? because adding new would not create an infinite loop. [image: Here is an explanation]

Comment: Hey, @Ikshita Puri, can you add more information to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Opinion, I would keep one View Controller that I will set in function of the user because the only differences between the current user and the other users on the profileViewController are the buttons "follow","edit profile" and "message" on the latest version of Instagram.

the current user on the latest version of instagram only has the button "edit profile" on his page and the other users who are not the current User have buttons such that "follow" and "Message"

[current user and other users profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/168IZ.jpg)

I would write something like

```
// if this is the currentUser show editButton and hide followButton
if profileUserEmail == currentUserEmail {
    followButton.isHidden = True
    editButton.isHidden = False
     messageButton.isHidden = True
// else show editButton ,messageButton and hide followButton
   }else{
       followButton.isHidden = False
        editButton.isHidden = True
        messageButton.isHidden = False
    }
```

the profileUserEmail is the email of the user whose you want to see the profile page

You can save the email of the currentUser when he logged in

```
   UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
```

and later you set this information in a constant

```
let currentUserEmail = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "email") as? String
```

Comment: Sounds great! But if I am scrolling through the HomeFeed and press the Username Button do I copy paste the UserProfileViewController or just present the original with the modifications?

Comment: As I wrote you present the UserProfileViewController with the modifications such that the followButton isHidden = True for example if the user whose you want to see the profile is the actual user.                                                                                         As I told , the only differences are the "follow","message" and "editProfileButton". So you hide and show them depending of the user.